# "Linear gradient" hampers all underlying items in QML

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I want to use [Client-side Decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-Side_Decoration) for my app and added the following code for the background gradient of the title-bar :

```
Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    header: ToolBar {
        LinearGradient {
            anchors.fill: parent
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#555555" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "black" }
            }
        }
```

[image]

But it hampers all the underlying buttons and also the search-bar gets useless.
There is no problem though when I use the `background` property of the `ToolBar` :

```
background: {
         color: "#31333600"
}
```

Is there any way to lower the title-bar background?

*I added buttons and the `TextField` after the `LinearGradient`.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are using the Quick Controls 2 Toolbar and customize it as documented here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-toolbar

For instance:

```
Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    header: ToolBar {
        background: LinearGradient {
            implicitHeight: 40
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#555555" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "black" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's some documentation for implicitHeight:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop

The toolbar will set its implicit height from the `implicitHeight` of the background.

Comment: What does implicitHeight mean? I cannot find any docs for it.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop